# TypeError: Cannot read property of null

Tags: javascript, node.js

I get the error in the title even though I have tried all the solutions. About the value of null;

```
If my code is ;

Output: TypeError: Cannot read property of null



case '!facebook':
face.Profile(facebook, function(result) {

let like = result.profiles.like;
let comments = result.profiles.comments;
               
if(like === null || comments === null){
//code.
}
else {
//code.
}
});
break;
```

Comment: Either *face* or *result* or *result.profiles* is null, it's impossible to tell from the posted code which one it might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to verify that each child of your object exists before you reference the next level. In your case, that means testing the existence of `result` and then `result.profiles` before trying to use any of the object values in `profiles`. See the code below.

Without seeing the rest of your `case` statement or how you're setting the value of `face`, it's hard to tell if you're going to run into other issues.

```js
case '!facebook':
face.Profile(facebook, function(result) {
    // Set default values
    let like = null;
    let comments = null;

    // Set values only if there's a result containing profiles
    if (result && result.profiles) {
        like = result.profiles.like;
        comments = result.profiles.comments;
    }
               
    if (like === null || comments === null){
        //code
    } else {
        //code
    }
});
break;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been dealing with this problem for 1 month. Good Job!